# xChart JSON Data, how do I update the data from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have implemented xCharts on my site and all is great but I'm looking to update the JSON data, shown below.

```
var data = {
    "xScale": "linear",
    "yScale": "linear",
    "main": [
        {
            "className": ".sub300",
            "data": [
                {
                    "x": 600,
                    "y": 2.5,
                },
                {
                    "x": 400,
                    "y": 3.5,
                },
                {
                    "x": 250,
                    "y": 4,
                },
                {
                    "x": 200,
                    "y": 4,
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

I want the user to select from a dropdown. This will then update the x & y values from a stored array.

I have never used JSON before but this xChart needs to use it, so how can I access/update/replace the x & y values with my own from an array?

Comment: Your example is not JSON data. JSON is a string. This is just js code. See json.org

Comment: Ok so this is just an array?

Comment: It's an object that contains, among other things, an array.

Comment: A very good js reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Comment: Update to Jonathans link targeted for js objects  - [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)